# Why doesn't "window.sessionStorage['foo'] ??= 'test'" work in Dart?

Tags: dart

The following code prints `null` twice whereas I was expecting (hoping?) that it would print `null` then `test`:

```dart
window.sessionStorage['foo'] = null;
print(window.sessionStorage['foo']);
window.sessionStorage['foo'] ??= 'test';
print(window.sessionStorage['foo']);
```

`sessionStorage` is marked `native` and the Storage class `extends Interceptor`. I don't know if either of those are related. Replacing `window.sessionStorage['foo']` with a simple field wrapped with a getter/setter seems to work as expected (so it does at least seem like `??=` can work with separate getter/setter).

**Edit:** The plot thickens. This code also prints `null` twice:

```
window.sessionStorage['danny'] = null;
print(window.sessionStorage['danny'] ?? 'VALUE-1');
window.sessionStorage['danny'] = window.sessionStorage['danny'] ?? 'VALUE-2';
print(window.sessionStorage['danny']);
```

Comment: Suspect this is a bug - seems like it may be writing the string "null". Have filed https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44416.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is printing twice null since doing `window.sessionStorage['foo'] = null;` doesn't set the `foo` key to `null` but actually to `"null"` and this not a bug in dart (you'd get the same behavior even in javascript) but rather than  a specification of the `sessionStorage` as you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> The keys and the values are always in the UTF-16 DOMString format, which uses two bytes per character. As with objects, integer keys are automatically converted to strings.

so this code `window.sessionStorage['foo'] ??= 'test';` won't set test because `sessionStorage['foo']` is not `null` but `"null"`.

To make your code working you should remove the key from the storage rather than settings it to null:

```
window.sessionStorage.remove('foo');
print(window.sessionStorage['foo']); // prints null
window.sessionStorage['foo'] ??= 'test';
print(window.sessionStorage['foo']); // prints test
```

Comment: Yeah :( I was trying to simplify some code to just use `??=` (which would set it to null if the right side was null, then overwrite it the next time around), but seems like that's not possible and I need to have an `if` check. Not a big deal, just a surprise!